# Jenkins-CI not properly signing apk

Tags: android, jenkins

I am using Jenkins-CI to build an Android app I'm working on at work. It appears to sign the apk just fine but when I try to install it I'm told that it isn't signing one resource file.  I decided to add a shell step after the ant build using jarsigner, again it appears to sign the apk fine but when I download the apk and try an adb install on my desktop I get an `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` error. Does anyone have a clue what would cause Jenkins-CI to not sign the apk correctly? I am using the same basic config at home and its working great. I'm running out of ideas on what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [Creating Your Android-Market-Ready APK](http://mussharapp.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-your-android-market-ready-apk.html)

Comment: Problem is, that shows the APK as properly signed.  I ended up writing a bash script that signs & zipaligns it ~15 minutes after the build has finished.  Not what I really want but its better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Jenkins node is installed on a machine running JDK 7?

I had the same problem.

With JDK 7, the signing process uses the 'SHA256' digest algorithm, which seems to be incompatible with Android.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to configure this behavior anywhere so my solution was to install JDK 6 on the node (see [How can I configure a Hudson job to use a specific JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747878/how-can-i-configure-a-hudson-job-to-use-a-specific-jdk) for this).

See also:

- [Transitioning Android dev from Linux to Windows: toolchain signes APK differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115111/transitioning-android-dev-from-linux-to-windows-toolchain-signes-apk-differentl)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JMQsdsKr7-0
- Relevant issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19567