# Error running automated tests by Jenkins

Tags: java, heroku, jenkins

When build my application with the command:

```
$> git push heroku master
```

The application works normally and I can run the automated testing, but when building my application by Jenkins, I get the following message from the browser:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /university/universityList.jsp at line 18

 15: 
 16:    <jsp:include page="universitiesMenu.jsp" />
 17: 
 18:        <jsp:include page="universities.jsp" />
 19: 
 20:    </div>
 21: 

 Stacktrace:

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    ...

    root cause

    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: br/usp/icmc/rest/ClientRestUniversity : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class br.usp.icmc.rest.ClientRestUniversity)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)

    ...

    root cause

    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: br/usp/icmc/rest/ClientRestUniversity : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class br.usp.icmc.rest.ClientRestUniversity)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2899)

    ...
```

Complete log file Jenkins: http://ricardoramos.url.ph/log_Jenkins.txt

Why when I run the command to push the heroku the application and automated testing works normally and when deployed by Jenkins I receiving an exception? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Based upon the stacktrace its the issue of the different versions of java being used for compiletime and runtime. Please ensure the java versions are same.

Comment: I have tested versions 7 and 8 of java in my system.properties file, but still giving the same problem. How do I know which versions of java'm using at compiletime and runtime on my project?

Comment: You can check the java version of the compiler in your IDE and for runtime you can check the version of java supported by your web or application server.

Comment: I checked the version of java 8 in my IDE and heroku well as the Jenkins both are also in version 8, was using version 7 of java in my project and upgraded to version 8.

Comment: Can you verify that Jetty is configured to use proper JDK version?

Comment: How to check if my Jetty is configured to use proper JDK version?

Comment: Did changing the version of the project work?

Comment: I was using version 7 of java in heroku, and never had a problem with that, but the now updated to version 8 as it is the version that is set in eclipse and installed on my ubuntu.

Comment: It looks ([Jetty changelog](https://webtide.com/jetty-9-2-0-released/)) that JDK 8 is supported as of version 9.2.0. This might be a potential place to look for compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Jenkins is using JDK version incompatible with one required by your source code.

You can read on configuring Jenkins and JDK [Configuring Your JDKs](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s05.html)

Also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747878/how-can-i-configure-a-hudson-job-to-use-a-specific-jdk)