# Hudson JDK 9 JAVA_HOME doesn't look like a JDK directory

Tags: java, hudson, java-9

I am using hudson v3.3.3. I want to use JDK 9.0.1 in a hudson job so I added JAVA_HOME into system configurations of hudson as below:

[image: Hudson JDK Home configuration]

It is giving an error saying `JAVA_HOME doesn't look like a JDK directory`. I have made sure the path I provide is JDK and not JRE. Also this is a valid JDK since I am using it in cmd/ANT without any problem. Could you please let me know the problem here?

**EDIT :** The JAVA_HOME looks like this:

[image: JDK 9 Home]

Comment: @nullpointer Please see the edit. I tried `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\ bin` but it gives different error: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin doesn't look like a JDK directory`

Comment: Seems like a bug, probably the version parsing might be based on the path. Could you try [explicitly specifying the path as an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268405/1746118) in one of your job and see if that works.

Comment: Might be similar to this Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25601

Comment: This is actually a bug just in validating JDK 9 home directory. I saved it as it is despite of the error message. My job is now running with JDK9 without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in hudson just in validating JDK 9 home directory. I saved JDK9 home as specified despite of the error message. My job is now running with JDK9 without any problems.